# Functions with generic parameter types

Tags: generics, f#, overloading, type-inference, typeclass

I am trying to figure out how to define a function that works on multiple types of parameters (e.g. int and int64). As I understand it, function overloading is not possible in F# (certainly the compiler complains). Take for example the following function.

```
let sqrt_int = function
    | n:int   -> int (sqrt (float n))
    | n:int64 -> int64 (sqrt (float n))
```

The compiler of course complains that the syntax is invalid (type constraints in pattern matching are not supported it seems), though I think this illustrates what I would like to achieve: a function that operates on several parameter types and returns a value of the according type. I have a feeling that this is possible in F# using some combination of generic types/type inference/pattern matching, but the syntax has eluded me. I've also tried using the :? operator (dynamic type tests) and *when* clauses in the pattern matching block, but this still produces all sorts errors.

As I am rather new to the language, I may very well be trying to do something impossible here, so please let me know if there is alternative solution.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Overloading is typically the bugaboo of type-inferenced languages (at least when, like F#, the type system isn't powerful enough to contain type-classes).  There are a number of choices you have in F#:

- Use overloading on methods (members of a type), in which case overloading works much like as in other .Net languages (you can ad-hoc overload members, provided calls can be distinguished by the number/type of parameters)
- Use "inline", "^", and static member constraints for ad-hoc overloading on functions (this is what most of the various math operators that need to work on int/float/etc.; the syntax here is weird, this is little-used apart from the F# library)
- Simulate type classes by passing an extra dictionary-of-operations parameter (this is what INumeric does in one of the F# PowerPack libraries to generalize various Math algorithms for arbitrary user-defined types)
- Fall back to dynamic typing (pass in an 'obj' parameter, do a dynamic type test, throw a runtime exception for bad type)

For your particular example, I would probably just use method overloading:

```
type MathOps =
    static member sqrt_int(x:int) = x |> float |> sqrt |> int
    static member sqrt_int(x:int64) = x |> float |> sqrt |> int64

let x = MathOps.sqrt_int 9
let y = MathOps.sqrt_int 100L
```

Comment: Good clarification - I think I understand what's going on now. Cheers for that. Having read up on things, It seems like F# is still missing a few of the nice features functional languages such as Haskell have. Perhaps these features will be implemented soon now that F# is a 1st class .NET language.

Comment: not sure if you want this to be a 'living' question or not but since the current f# release now no longer needs the OverloadId attrib (yey!) you may want to adjust the answer...

Comment: Thanks, I'd already updated the code, but forgot to update the prose.

Comment: @Noldorin: "Perhaps these features will be implemented soon now that F# is a 1st class .NET language". I seriously doubt it given the lack of compelling examples.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Isn't this very question a compelling example? I expected that a modern language would have this feature. That function overloading should be on every language designers list. This is something that can be worked around but WHY!! It should just work.

Comment: @Gorgen: I don't believe it is, no. The problem is that is never "just works". Overloading in languages like C++ and C# grates against type inference. Overloading in languages like Haskell using features like type classes can massively degrade the performance of basic arithmetic operations when you least expect it. Standard ML chose ad-hoc polymorphism to cover a single special case (int vs float) but no others (e.g. scalar vs vector). OCaml has no overloading at all but recently adopted a solution known as "delimited" overloading.

Comment: Scala and C# 3 chose the compromise of "local" type inference which is just lame. F# chose the pragmatic compromise of some overloading (arithmetic operators) but in a framework that guarantees static resolution and no dispatch so it is always fast. These trade-offs are known but not solved. My personal preference is the F# solution because it solves the overloading where it matters most (arithmetic) without introducing awful performance characteristics where they often matter the most (arithmetic!).

Comment: @Jon Harrop: I was looking at this question because I had the same problem. I went the route with two members of a class. Why is the function overloading working with class members but not with free functions? Is it easier for the type inference when it is a class?

Comment: @Gorgen: Exactly. Overloading screws with type inference so F# relegates it to the OO side where type inference is already screwed.

Comment: Multiple dispatch doesn't mean poor performance.  It's a central design principle in Julia, so much so that one of its creators said they took it further than any other non-research language.  Yet Julia is designed primarily for high-performance numerical computing and typically out-performs C.

Comment: @GatesDA "Julia [...] typically out-performs C"? I would like to see an example for that. To my knowledge, they only claim to be within a small factor (>1) compared to C for many problems, (which is still much faster than most higher-level languages).

Comment: This was asked 6 years ago?! So F# still has no better way of doing this today?

Answer (score 20):

This works:

```
type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, n:int  ) = int   (sqrt (float n))
    static member ($) (T, n:int64) = int64 (sqrt (float n))

let inline sqrt_int (x:'t) :'t = T $ x
```

It uses static constraints and overloading, which makes a compile-time lookup on the type of the argument.

The static constraints are automatically generated in presence of an operator (operator `$` in this case) but it can always be written by hand:

```
type T = T with
    static member Sqr (T, n:int  ) = int   (sqrt (float n))
    static member Sqr (T, n:int64) = int64 (sqrt (float n))

let inline sqrt_int (x:'N) :'N = ((^T or ^N) : (static member Sqr: ^T * ^N -> _) T, x)
```

More about this [here](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/11/15/typeclasses-for-fsharp/).

Comment: This is a very nice improvement over the solution provided by Brian and Mauricio, it has the benefit of a function without the dot-notation (compare Brian's) and it adds compile-time type checking (compare Mauricio's). Would you care to elaborate in your answer on how this works and whether the operator-definition is a requirement?

Comment: Thanks @Abel, I did elaborate a bit more about the solution and included a link to a blog entry with more details. Mauricio's answer takes a very different approach which is also valid, it uses always the same code for all types by casting to-from ``float`` which is less code but if you want to work with big integers you may run into a limitation.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this can be done. Take a look at [this hubFS thread](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/5343.aspx).

In this case, the solution would be:

```
let inline retype (x:'a) : 'b = (# "" x : 'b #)
let inline sqrt_int (n:'a) = retype (sqrt (float n)) : 'a
```

**Caveat**: no compile-time type checking. I.e. `sqrt_int "blabla"` compiles fine but you'll get a FormatException at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the solution (though it's not as straightforward as I might have hoped). Just to clarify, I would want something like this?

let inline sqrt_int (n:^a) = retype (sqrt (float n)) : ^a

Comment: Yup, that works. However, be aware that with this you lose compile-time type checking. I.e. sqrt_int "blabla" type-checks although you'll get a FormatException at runtime.

Comment: Ok, so there's really no point of using the hat operator in this case, right? If I happened to be using an arithmetic operator such as * in the function (before the cast), would that insure the compile-time check?

Comment: Yes, in this case a normal type parameter works too: let inline sqrt_int (n:'a) = retype (sqrt (float n)) : 'a
Not sure what you mean with the arithmetic operator.

Comment: What is that `(# "" x : 'b #)` beast? The compiler tells me, that construct is deprecated and should be only used in the F# library. And good luck googling for `(#`...

Answer (score 10):

Here's another way using runtime type checks...

```
let sqrt_int<'a> (x:'a) : 'a = // '
    match box x with
    | :? int as i -> downcast (i |> float |> sqrt |> int |> box)
    | :? int64 as i -> downcast (i |> float |> sqrt |> int64 |> box)
    | _ -> failwith "boo"

let a = sqrt_int 9
let b = sqrt_int 100L
let c = sqrt_int "foo" // boom
```

Comment: Interesting. Now I have too many options! One question: why you need the generic specifier <'a> when you specify a type constraint on x. I thought they were equivalent syntaxes.

Comment: You can indeed omit the <'a> (try it).  Note the potential perf difference; the method-overloading determines which version at compile-time, whereas this version does run-time type-checking.  (It might be that 'sqrt' overwhelms these considerations, though, I haven't measured.)

Comment: And of course the other difference is that this version compiles (and throws at runtime) for non-ints, whereas the method overloading version will compile-time error for non-ints.

Answer (score 3):

Not to take away from the correct answers already provided, but you can in fact use type constraints in pattern matching. The syntax is:

```
| :? type ->
```

Or if you want to combine type checking and casting:

```
| :? type as foo ->
```

Comment: That's what I initially thought I might be able to do. Unfortunately it gives a "runtime coercion" error (error FS0008). Together with the retype function provided in a link in mausch's post, it should however work as an alternative to the inline keyword if I understand it properly.

Comment: the runtime coercion can be avoided by boxing the variable the type is matched on using `match box variable with`