# Regarding F# Object Oriented Programming

Tags: f#, oop

There's this dichotomy in the way we can create classes in f# which really bothers me. I can create classes using either an implicit format or an explicit one. But some of the features that I want are only available for use with the implicit format and some are only available for use with the explicit format.

For example:

1. I can't use `let inline`* (or `let` alone) inside an explicitly defined class.
2. The only way (that I know) to define immutable **public** fields (not properties*) inside an implicitly defined class is the `val bla : bla` syntax.

   But there's a redundancy here. Since I'll end up with two copy of the same immutable data, one private, one public (because in the implicit mode the constructor parameters persist throughout the class existence)
3. (Not so relevant) The need to use attributes for method overloading and for field's defaults is rather off putting.

Is there anyway I can work around this?

*For performance reasons

EDIT: Turns out I'm wrong about both points (Thanks Ganesh Sittampalam & MichaelGG).

1. While I can't use `let inline` in both implicit & explicit class definition, I can use `member inline` just fine, which I assume does the same thing.
2. Apparently with the latest F# there's no longer any redundancy since any parameters not used in the class body are local to the constructor.
3. [Will be gone](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/permalink/10385/10335/ShowThread.aspx#10335) in the next F# release.

Comment: "For performance reasons"? Can't say I like the sound of that ;)

Comment: It's mostly number crunching related to graphics programming. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/09/07/745085.aspx.

Comment: Your question does not give a hint to the problem you are trying to solve. I assume that you want to emulate C++ style Object-Oriented Programming in F#. (Correct me if your are not!). But why did you need this in a functional language? I suppose this is particular to the problem you are working on and it might be interesting if you make detailed post about it here.

Comment: Do the constructor parameters still persist with the Beta1 compiler? I thought they'd removed that for cases where they're not actually needed.

Comment: @Ganesh Sittampalam: Where did you read this? and how do they determine whether they're needed or not? Thanks.

Comment: @Vijay Mathew: I'm using classes because I can't overload operators by type using only functions. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501069/f-functions-with-generic-parameter-types/501356#501356

Comment: @Dave Berk: I got it from the "Optimizations for Class and Struct representations" section of the detailed release notes. That explains what should be removed, albeit not very precisely: http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/05/20/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-may-2009-ctp-update-and-visual-studio-2010-beta1-releases.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not help, but you can make members inline. "member inline private" works fine.

Comment: It does help. Thanks. Means I'll settle on using the explicit syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For `let inline`, you can work around by moving it outside the class and explicitly passing any values you need from inside the scope of the class when calling it. Since it'll be inlined, there'll be no performance penalty for doing this.