# F# - Overload Functions

Tags: f#

Is there a way to do somehow overload a function?

Let's take those 3 functions:

```
// Returns StringPropertyInfo
let stringProperty (expr:Expr<'a -> string>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = 
    cfg.Property expr

// Returns DatePropertyInfo
let dateProperty (expr:Expr<'a -> System.DateTime>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = 
    cfg.Property expr

// Returns BytePropertyInfo
let byteProperty (expr:Expr<'a -> System.Byte>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) =
     cfg.Property expr
```

is there a way to merge them all into just:

```
let property expr cfg = ....
```

if not, whats the most neat way to accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer, no. There's another question dealing with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936143/is-it-possible-to-do-function-overloading-in-f).

You can however overload methods in classes etc. otherwise the .NET integration wouldn't work too well. This is one possible solution albeit not in my eyes, a pretty one.

You could put them in different sub-modules.

Perhaps you could make a generic function and decide the return type through one of the parameters. I'm too much of a newbie when it comes to the type inference to say for certain though.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use an approach based on discriminated unions, then I think the declaration is more suitable (as you don't need to manipulate with quotations). Slight modification of the type suggested by Alex is:

```
type PropertyInfo<'a> =
  | String of Expr<'a -> string>
  | Date of Expr<'a -> System.DateTime>
  | ...
```

Then you'd write something like:

```
let property (pi:PropertyInfo<'a>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) =
  match pi with
  | String e -> cfg.Property e
  | ...

cfg |> property (String <@ fun e -> e.Foo @>)
```

Another option would be to implement `property` as a static member of a type, in which case you can use usual overloading (similar to C#). Something like:

```
type EF = 
  static member property (expr:Expr<'a -> string>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = 
    cfg.Property expr
  static member property (expr:Expr<'a -> System.DateTime>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = 
    cfg.Property expr
  static member property (expr:Expr<'a -> System.Byte>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) =
     cfg.Property expr
```

Then you'd write:

```
cfg |> EF.property <@ e -> e.Foo @>
```

Finally, you could also make it a bit simpler (but less safer) by making the function fully generic and doing dynamic type test (to decide what return type is used). Something like:

```
let property<'a, 'r> (e:Expr<'a -> 'r>) (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) =
  if typeof<'r> = typeof<string> then
    // ...
```

Comment: Exactly! - However it seems like you cant define generics in a discriminated union? Atleast `| String of Expr<'a -> string>` throws a compiler error saying `The type parameter 'a' is not defined`

Comment: @ebb: That was my mistake - the updated answer should work (the type `PropertyInfo` needs to be itself generic - so that it can have a type variable `'a` inside).

Comment: I see.. however it looks like the discriminated union is not a viable option since those I want to overload will return different objects.

Answer (score 7):

i think a discriminated union is your friend in this instance, you would have something like

```
type PropertyInfo = 
| StringPropertyInfo of string
| DatePropertyInfo of System.DateTime
| BytePropertyInfo of byte
```

and then would match on it and do appropriate action returning the union in one function...

Comment: I don't think this will be easy to use. Using this discriminated union, you'd have to work with `Expr<'a -> PropertyInfo>`, but the `Property` method expects a different quotation - so the OP would have to do some pre-processing of quotations to get it working. However, wrapping the whole quotation in a discriminated union should be easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

One semi-ugly way to get what you're looking for would be to generalize it a bit and use:

```
let inline property expr cfg =
    (^t : (member Property : Expr<'a -> 'b> -> 'c)(cfg, expr))
```

However, this can be applied to values of types other than `EntityInfo<'a>`, as long as they have a `Property` member with the right signature.