# Binary comparison operators on generic types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic class that takes a type `T`.  Within this class I have a method were I need to compare a type `T` to another type `T` such as:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MaxValue
    {
        // Implimentation for MaxValue
    }

    public T MyMethod(T argument)
    {
        if(argument > this.MaxValue)
        {
             // Then do something
        }
    }
}
```

The comparison operation inside of `MyMethod` fails with Compiler Error [CS0019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63h61ky(VS.71).aspx).  Is it possible to add a constraint to `T` to make this work?  I tried adding a `where T: IComparable<T>` to the class definition to no avail.

Comment: It's Impossible =( . However there is an open source math library that tries to deal with it, have to recall the name...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding constraint to make sure that the type implements `IComparable<T>` is a way to go. However, you cannot use the `<` operator - the interface provides a method `CompareTo` to do the same thing:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IComparable<T> { 
    public T MaxValue  { 
        // Implimentation for MaxValue 
    } 

    public T MyMethod(T argument) { 
        if(argument.CompareTo(this.MaxValue) > 0){ 
             // Then do something 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If you needed other numeric operators than just comparison, the situation is more difficult, because you cannot add constraint to support for example `+` operator and there is no corresponding interface. Some ideas about this [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404731/polymorphic-numerics-on-net-and-in-c/2406328#2406328).

Comment: Good call Tomas.  I found a blog post at http://blogs.telerik.com/hristoborisov/posts/09-01-10/comparing_generic_types.aspx regarding this exact issue shortly after I asked the question that confirms what you are saying.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible, operator constraints are unfortunately not allowed in c#. 
`where T: IComparable<T>`
should work just fine, but you have to use other semantics: CompareTo method instead of >,< and == operators.

Comment: Yes and I'm not sure the OP is married to the use of operators for this.

Comment: Hmm..I don't really understood your comment.

Comment: he meant that the OP is not obliged to use those operators. He can use any other way, als long is it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `IComparable<T>`'s `CompareTo` method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need anything special here. `Comparer<T>.Default` offers a `.Compare` method that will do everything you need without requiring any additional generic constraints (which tend to propagate horribly). It works for both `IComparable<T>` and `IComparable`, and supports classes, structs and `Nullable<T>`. Job done.

For info, this is how the LINQ `Max` / `Min` implementations work, and likewise `List<T>.Sort`. So a common and well supported part of the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible, but there are workarounds.

[I posted mine in a different question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756954/arithmetic-operator-overloading-for-a-generic-class-in-c/756979#756979)