# F#: how to create matrix of elements of any other type except Double

Tags: f#, matrix, types

I'm a beginner in F#. I know that there is the way to create Double Matrix using PowerPack.dll:

```
let B = matrix [ [ 1.0; 7.0 ];
                 [ 1.0; 3.0 ] ]
```

How can I create matrix with elements of my own type (for example with [,] instead of Double), so it would look like:

```
let B = matrix [ [ [1,2]; [3,4] ];
                 [ [7,8]; [5,6] ] ]
```

Comment: please see this blog post:
http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/f-inumerics-interface-and-matrix-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Matrix` is a particularly mathematical type for working with *numbers*.

If you just want to arrange arbitrary elements in a rectangular shape, use standard F# `list`s or `array`s.

Comment: Matrix is a particularly mathematical type for working with numbers. - it is not true. See another answers. Matrix is generic and can be used for working with any type.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that matrix should be mainly used when working with numbers. The standard non-generic matrix type (which you can create using the `matrix` function) works with numbers of type `float`. If you want to work with other numeric types, you can use `Matrix.Generic` module, which contains functionality for working with generic matrices (containing any types).

You can use generic matrix for storing tuples as well (if you want). A generic matrix can be created using the `ofList` function. You can also define a function for this to get a nicer syntax:

```
let anymatrix = Matrix.Generic.ofList
let B = anymatrix [ [ [1,2]; [3,4] ]; 
                    [ [7,8]; [5,6] ] ]
```

To work with generic matrices, you can use the `Matrix.Generic` module:

```
let Bt = Matrix.Generic.transpose B
```

Typically, you'll use matrices only with numeric types, because many of the operations require some arithmetics in order to work. This will work for all basic numeric types (such as `int`) and you can also provide arithmetics for your own type using `GlobalAssociations` [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225949/does-f-have-generic-arithmetic-support).

However, if you want to simply store some values then there are other (more suitable) data types. You can also use `Array2D` which represents a mutable two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

Tomas already gives a good answer. I will comment a bit here.

Let's see some source code in matrix.fsi from PowerPack:

```
type matrix = Matrix<float>
```

so matrix is a concrete type instantiated from the meta type Matrix. You could also use

```
type intmatrix = Matrix<int>
```

to define your int matrix type.

but to use something like:

```
let B = matrix [ [ 1.0; 7.0 ];
                 [ 1.0; 3.0 ] ]
```

We need another function called matrix, whose deceleration as

```
val matrix : seq<#seq<float>> -> matrix
```

let's see its implementation in matrix.fs:

```
let matrix ll = Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix.ofSeq ll
```

while Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix module is for double(in f# float) matrix, Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Matrix.Generics is for generic matrix. You can implement your intmatrix 'constructor'.

put it together:

```
type intmatrix = Matrix<int>
let intmatrix ll = Matrix.Generic.ofSeq  ll
let C = intmatrix [ [1;2]; [3;4] ];
```