# Type of addition (+) in F#

Tags: types, f#, ocaml, inline

I just learned that OCAML have to have a `.` postfix for doing float arithmetic. An example would be `3. +. 4.` which equals `7.` (float). However, F# handles float and integer arithmetic in the same way, so both `3 + 4` (int) and `3. + 4.` (float) works.

F# have `+` naturally assigned to int so `let add a b = a + b` is of type `int -> int -> int`. And indeed `(+)` gives me `val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@6-1>`.

That leads to the following sequence which I think quite counter-intuitive:

```
> 3. + 4.;;
val it : float = 7.0
> (+);;
val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@8-2>
```

*So my question is:* Is the "overloading" done by a special mechanism/case in the compiler or is this a language-wide thing so I potentially can define a function called `add` (or anything else) which have a one definition for integers and one for floats (or any other type.)

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732672/how-to-write-a-function-for-generic-numbers/4738404#4738404

Comment: @Daniel Compile-time type constrains. Nice, thanks :) However, the question still stands: is this how it is done in F#?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Generic functions can only be written `inline`, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Briefly, F# has an ad-hoc-overloading mechanism via the `inline` keyword and "static member constraints".  There is some further magic specific to the built-in math operators, which magically assumes type `int` the absence of other constraints.  `(+)` is just about the most special/magical thing in all of F#, so it does not make for a nice introduction to the language/type system.

In general, "overloading" is difficult for statically-typed, type-inferred languages.  F#'s choices here are very pragmatic.  OCaml does a different, simple, pragmatic thing (no overloading).  Haskell does a different, complex-but-elegant thing (type classes).  They're all somewhat reasonable points in the language/library design space.

Comment: Thanks, your link in the comment and this description was all I need :)

Answer (score 7):

Overloaded functions (and operators) must be marked `inline` in F#. This is because they depend on [explicit member constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx). Those constraints are resolved at compile time. A function `let inline add a b = a + b` has the type `'a -> 'b -> 'c (requires member (+))` where `+` is a static function/operator. You can't do this in C#; it doesn't have static member constraints.

```
let inline add a b = a + b
add 1 2 //works
add 1.0 2.0 //also works
```

Comment: +1 Cool :) I see from the type of the function that it uses compile type constraints. However, this doesn't answer the question entirely. What is the definition of `(+)` really when it works on both?

Comment: Something like: `'a -> 'b -> 'c (requires member (+))` That means, it works for any type having a static member `(+)`.

Comment: What is `(+)`? :) It tells me it is `int -> int -> int` but it works on float, why? I'm sorry if it isn't clear what I mean :/

Comment: You can see the code here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs  
It is gory and you don't want to know the details.  Some of it is specific compiler magic for the built-in math operators.  More generally, you can use `inline` and static member constraints to do similar duck-typing stuff in user code, but it is also gory and you do not want to know the details.  The short answer is: "magic".

Comment: @lass: It has the type `int -> int -> int` unless you mark it `inline`. So, yes, F# seems to pick `int` by default, unless it can infer a better type based on usage (i.e., if your initial call to the function uses float parameters, for example).

Comment: @lass: I think you may be confusing the signature of `+` with that of your function using `+`. `+` is generic, but a function using it is not, unless marked `inline`. This is because use of the operator depends on the presence of a static member. (Sorry if I'm sounding repetitive.)

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, I think you're right. F# is a lot more complex than I thought. I appreciate your helpfulness :-)

Comment: @lass: Yes, but I find it's the type of complexity that makes things simpler. However, it can drive you crazy trying to figure out how some of it works.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Brian´s answer and link:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs

I found some definitions in the code:

```
let inline (+) (x:int) (y:int) = (# "add" x y : int #)
```

and

```
let inline (+) (x: ^T) (y: ^U) : ^V = 
     AdditionDynamic<(^T),(^U),(^V)>  x y 
     when ^T : int32       and ^U : int32      = (# "add" x y : int32 #)
     when ^T : float       and ^U : float      = (# "add" x y : float #)
     when ^T : float32     and ^U : float32    = (# "add" x y : float32 #)
     ...
```

And the `AdditionDynamic` is defined here (loads of static stuff and CIL):
https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L2374

Fun stuff:

```
(# "add" 1 2 : int32 #)
```

works, and gives 3 as output (with a warning saying you shouldn't do this.)

Comment: Yes the FSharp.Core library has some magic to access underlying IL constructs when there is no .NET API to do it.  You should not use the `(# ... #)` stuff in your own code, it is a bug that the compiler does not reject this outright (and future versions of the compiler will reject it outright).

Comment: @Brian: Why shouldn't we be able to write inline IL? It's not a bug; it's a feature. :-)