# Why would I use the keyword "inline" for an Active Pattern?

Tags: f#, inline, active-pattern

I still cannot understand why I would use the keyword `inline` for a function.

What does it give me that I don't already have?

```
let inline (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) x =
 match sign x with
 | 1 -> Positive
 | -1 -> Negative
 | _ -> Neutral
```

Comment: The answer could be easily found in documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx

Comment: speed for one (sometimes)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192390/make-function-work-with-all-numeric-types-int-float-long and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285493/type-of-addition-in-fthere

Comment: Overloaded functions (and operators) must be marked inline in F#

Comment: Of interest: [Inline Fun Part I](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/10/05/inlinefun/) Also check out parts II, III, and IV.

Comment: Of interest: [Use of `inline` in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754862/use-of-inline-in-f)

Comment: The use of `inline` for performance is obvious. The use of `inline` for typing is not so obvious or is even known to people new to F#. As such when I went to search previous SO questions tagged with `inline` I was surprised at how many had useful information but were missing the `inline` tag. So I judiciously added the `inline` tag. If you now read the results of this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23+inline) you will find lots of useful information related to `inline`. Once you have a specific Q&A open search for inline, most of the good info is in the answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, it may be easier to understand what `inline` gives you if you try to remove the keyword:

```
let (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) x =
    match sign x with
    | 1 -> Positive
    | -1 -> Negative
    | _ -> Neutral
```

This active pattern has the type `float -> Choice<unit,unit,unit>`. Notice that the compiler has inferred that it only works for `float` input.

The consequences of this may be most apparent if we also define a function that uses this pattern, e.g. one that determines if a number is a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number):

```
let isNatural = function
    | Positive -> true
    | _ -> false
```

This function has the type `float -> bool`, which means that you can use it only with `float` input:

```
> isNatural 1.;;
val it : bool = true
> isNatural 1;;

>   isNatural 1;;
  ----------^

stdin(4,11): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    float    
but here has type
    int
```

What if you want to be able to determine that both `float`, `int`, `int64`, etcetera, are natural numbers? Should you duplicate these functions for all input types?

You don't have to. You can `inline` the functions:

```
let inline (|Positive|Neutral|Negative|) x =
    match sign x with
    | 1 -> Positive
    | -1 -> Negative
    | _ -> Neutral

let inline isNatural x =
    match x with
    | Positive -> true
    | _ -> false
```

Because of the `inline` keyword, the compiler keeps the type of the functions generic:

```
> 
val inline ( |Positive|Neutral|Negative| ) :
  x: ^a -> Choice<unit,unit,unit> when  ^a : (member get_Sign :  ^a -> int)
val inline isNatural : x: ^a -> bool when  ^a : (member get_Sign :  ^a -> int)
```

This means that you can use *any* type for input, as long as there exists a function `get_Sign` that takes that type as input, and returns `int`.

You can now call the functions with both `float`, `int`, and other numeric types:

```
> isNatural 1.;;
val it : bool = true
> isNatural 1;;
val it : bool = true
```

Comment: Thanks mark. I interpreted the documentation for inline to be for performance only. I still think this was an important question regardless of people voting it down. Thanks again.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I agree that what you were seeking was valid, but the question was specific to Active Patterns and that was easily answered. If you had asked the question differently I think you would have achieved the desired result. It took me a while to get better at asking certain types of questions without stepping on the mines. For example someone recently asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538273/is-there-any-documentation-on-how-to-use-glimpse-with-f-and-suave) about documentation and the question was closed, yet I asked similar questions and received up-votes.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I find that if I have a question to ask I do all of the work I can, e.g. write code, fix bugs, read documents, and then only after all of that fails, I write up what I did and where I need help and above all make sure it is an objective question, then I get good quick answers, usually with upvotes. Yes I did ask about the site being shut down and get lots of love (sarcasm) but I fully expected it.

Comment: @ScottNimrod It is not mob mentality it is an ethos.