# F# - multiply int by float

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Probably a silly question, but I just got started with F# and I've got a little problem.

Say I have a function like this:

```
let multiplyByTwo x = x * 2
```

When I call this like this:

```
let result = multiplyByTwo 5
```

Everything is alright, the result is 10.

When I call it like this:

```
let result = multiplyByTwo 2.5
```

I expect to get 5 or 5.0 as a result. The actual result however is this:

> let result = multiplyByTwo 2.5;;
>     ---------------------------------^^^
>
> stdin(4,28): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>
> ```
> int
> ```
>
> but here has type
>
> ```
> float
> ```

Because I want this function to be somewhat generic (i.e. accept both floating point numbers and integers), I don't like this. My question of course: how does one solve this?

Comment: I don't know much about F# hence the comment but I presume the '2' in your function is being regarded as an int & is expecting x to be an int also, is there some way you can cast?

Comment: The 'incompatibility' of `float` and `int` used to really bug me when I started with F#, but after a couple of years, I've slowly come round to the usefulness of considering them as different types. Oftentimes it has forced me to ask myself what I really *want*.

Comment: I believe this is a language flaw and my workaround was to use floats for everything when I want to deal with real numbers and don't care about performance or accuracy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let inline mulBy2 x = (float x) * 2.0

let a = mulBy2 3 // 6.0 : float
let b = mulBy2 2.5 // 5.0 : float
let c = mulBy2 "4" // 8.0 : float
```

Comment: I find this method to be the cleanest way. Looks like a good solution. I just don't fully understand the 'inline' keyword yet (it appears that it parses the input, but I dont know when to use and when not to use it), but I'll look into that on Google.

Comment: From MSDN: "Without the inline modifier, type inference forces the function to take a specific type, in this case int. But with the inline modifier, the function is also inferred to have a statically resolved type parameter. This means that the function accepts any type that supports a conversion to float."

Answer (score 14):

When you write a numeric literal in F# (such as `2` or `3.14`), the compiler treats that as a value of a specific type and so code that uses numeric literals will not be polymorphic. You can either convert input to a single type and work with that type (like `float` in desco's answer) or use more advanced features of F#...

Certain numeric operations can be written in a polymorphic way, if you mark the code as `inline` (this way, the compiler can represent additional constraints and statically resolve them) and if you only use polymorphic primitives (with additional static constraints).

Standard operators are polymorpic in `inline` functions and the F# library provides a way to get polymorphic value representing 1 and 0 (though not 2), but that's enough to write the function you wanted:

```
let inline twoTimes n = 
  let one = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  n * (one + one)

twoTimes 2
twoTimes 2.0
```

If you want to make this nicer, you can define a numeric literal (see [Daniel's answer to earlier StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732672/how-to-write-a-function-for-generic-numbers)) and then you can actually write just:

```
let inline twoTimes n = n * 2G
```

The special numeric literal `2G` is translated to a call to a function of `NumericLiteralG` which sums specified number of generic 1 values using the technique I used above (so it won't be efficient for large numbers!) For more information, you see also my recent article on [writing generic numeric code in F#](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx).

Comment: I accepted desco's answer because it's the easiest (and imho cleanest) solution, but I thank you for you great post! Btw, I read on your website that you are one of Don Syme's students, nice!

Comment: Nice. I Figured the`"answer" would be something todowih getting rid of the literal, didn't have scooby doo how`to do it though.

Comment: @LeonCullens If you're happy with the result being `float`, then the answer by @desco is the best option. Don Syme is actually still my (second) PhD supervisor :-).

Comment: Yep, I don't really care about the results of the function, as long as I can assign any numeric parameter to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't afraid using "little hacks", this might be useful:

```
// Copied from Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.retype
[<NoDynamicInvocation>]
let inline retype (x:'a) : 'b = (# "" x : 'b #)

let inline multiplyByTwo (x:'a) = x * (retype 2:'a)

// use
let result1 = multiplyByTwo 5 // 10
let result2 = multiplyByTwo 2.5 // 5.0
```

This construct is not type safe since type checking is done in runtime. Also, quotations are relatively slow.