# Can I define a function that is generic across the measure dimension?

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I want to be able generate random numbers of a specific range that are measures where `<'T>` could be `[<Measure>] type X` or `[<Measure>] type Y`

```
let GenerateLine<'T> (rnd:System.Random, min:int<_>, max:int<_>) : (int<_> * int<_>) =
  let v1:int< 'T > = rnd.Next(int(min),int(max)+1)
  let v2:int< 'T > = rnd.Next(int(min),int(max)+1)
  (v1,v2)
```

I've also tried the same above with the `inline` keyword after `let`

and

```
let GenerateLine (rnd:System.Random, min max) =
  let v1 = rnd.Next(min,max+1) * LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  let v2 = rnd.Next(min,max+1) * LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  (v1,v2)
```

also

```
let GenerateLine< ^T> (rnd:System.Random, min:< ^T >, max:< ^T > ) =
```

but I seem to be having no figuring this out or following the logic behind things like 
[How to write a function for generic numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732672/how-to-write-a-function-for-generic-numbers?lq=1)

How do you write a method/function that is generic across measures?

Comment: You need to use [Int32WithMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806510.aspx) to convert the plain `int`s to `int<'T>`.

Comment: how? one which of the attempted signatures?

Comment: Int32WithMeasure is a function - use GenericOne as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I meant in my comment:

```
let GenerateLine (rnd:System.Random, min:int<'t>, max:int<'t>) : (int<'t> * int<'t>) =
  let v1 = rnd.Next(int(min),int(max)+1) |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure
  let v2 = rnd.Next(int(min),int(max)+1) |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure
  (v1,v2)
```

I've moved some of your annotations around, but you could mostly stick to what you had.  The one critical thing is that if you want to give your function an explicit generic parameter, you need to mark it with the `Measure` attribute:

```
let GenerateLine<[<Measure>]'t> ...
```

or else the compiler expects it to be a regular generic type parameter.  But I generally prefer to let type inference handle the fact that the function is generic anyway.

Comment: +1 with this I was able to remove all type annotations and types from the function definition besides the `System.Random` guy.