# F# automatic number type

Tags: parameters, f#, functional-programming

Is there a was to make a function in F# working for each type of number. I would like to pass in a number of a type and get the same type back.

Here a short example:

```
let Primes max=
    let rec loop primes acc=
        match acc with
        |x::xs ->   let filtered = acc |> List.filter (fun y -> y%x <> 0)
                    loop (x::primes) filtered
        |[] -> primes |> List.rev
    loop [] [2..max]
```

Now I can only pass in int32, but I want to pass in uint64 or bigint if necessary.

Comment: Check this question - [How to write a function for generic numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732672/how-to-write-a-function-for-generic-numbers) It covers the topic in more detail than one would ever need.

Comment: Tank you for the quick reply :D