# Why F# fails to have type inference for list elements?

Tags: list, f#, inline, inference

```
I was trying to put both int and float into a list construction:

> let l2=[1;2.0];;

  let l2=[1;2.0];;
  ----------^^^

stdin(50,11): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int
but here has type
    float
>
```

Well, if I write let l3=[1,2.0] in Haskell it works to construct the list to have all "fractional" elements. Why F# doesn't support automatic type inference? F# is based on .net and both Int and Float are Object type, right? Why Int and Float couldn't be put into one list, while some elements are having type promotion or conversion automatically? Seems the type system of F# makes it very difficult to write more generic programs.

Any hints?

Comment: So what do you want the elements of the list to be? float / int / obj?

Comment: Seems to me as if automatic type inference is working just fine.  The list elements are of type `int` because that's what the type of the first element you put in is.  That you were expecting it to infer a `float` is a failing of your understanding of the language, not a failing of the language.

Comment: Suddenly I'm really curious to know how Haskell figures this out.

Comment: @DanielPratt In Haskell, the expression `[1,2.0]` has the type `Fractional t => [t]`, which means that all elements in the list belong to the *typeclass* `Fractional`. I don't know exactly how GHC (the Haskell compiler I use) figures it out, but it seems to me that it infers the most general type that fits *the entire* expression.

Comment: Have you ever Googled for Heterogeneous list and Homogenous list? You might find what you seek. Also remember that a list is really just a cons of items, if you change out cons you can get a heterogeneous list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

F# doesn't have typeclasses like Haskell. While it's based on .NET, the only type in common between `int` and `float` is `obj`, and `obj` offers no operators that enable you to perform arithmetic.

Still, you *can* define a list that contains both `int` and `float` values:

```
let l : obj list = [1; 2.0]
```

This is close to **useless**, though, because you can't *do* anything with these values unless you attempt to downcast them. It's also **unsafe**, because such a list can easily contain values that aren't numbers:

```
let l : obj list = [1; 2.0; "foo"]
```

All is not lost, however, because you can use the `inline` keyword to let the compiler figure out what operators are needed for various input:

```
type Direction = Left = -1 | Straight = 0 | Right = 1

let inline turn (x1, y1) (x2, y2) (x3, y3) =
    let prod = (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)
    if prod > LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Direction.Left
    elif prod < LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then Direction.Right
    else Direction.Straight
```

This function has the following type:

```
val inline turn :
  x1: ^a * y1: ^f -> x2: ^b * y2: ^g -> x3: ^j * y3: ^e -> Direction
    when ( ^b or  ^a) : (static member ( - ) :  ^b *  ^a ->  ^c) and
         ( ^j or  ^a) : (static member ( - ) :  ^j *  ^a ->  ^i) and
         ( ^c or  ^d) : (static member ( * ) :  ^c *  ^d ->  ^l) and
         ( ^e or  ^f) : (static member ( - ) :  ^e *  ^f ->  ^d) and
         ( ^g or  ^f) : (static member ( - ) :  ^g *  ^f ->  ^h) and
         ( ^h or  ^i) : (static member ( * ) :  ^h *  ^i ->  ^k) and
         ( ^l or  ^k) : (static member ( - ) :  ^l *  ^k ->  ^m) and
          ^m : (static member get_Zero : ->  ^m) and  ^m : comparison
```

It states that a `^a` and `^b` are types that support the static operator `-` that, when used, returns the type `^c`, which supports the static operator `*`, and so on.

This example is taken from [my convex hull example](https://github.com/ploeh/Hull).

It can be used with both `int` and `float` lists, because both types support the required operators:

```
> turn (1,2) (3,3) (2,1);;
val it : Direction = Right
> turn (1.0,2.0) (3.0,3.0) (2.0,1.0);;
val it : Direction = Right
```

This is hardly as elegant as Haskell, but it can be used in a pinch. In practice, though, I don't miss it much. I rarely miss *generic arithmetic* in my professional life; I find it telling that some of the most commercially successful programming languages (Java, C#) don't support generic arithmetic.

Comment: If you want to make the types a bit less hairy, you may want to consider the technique in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739433/82959.