# How can I unify these two float functions?

Tags: generics, f#, numbers, type-conversion, type-inference

I found this [neat trick](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) of calculating the mean and the standard deviation in one pass over the data. I wanted to have this working for `float32` and `float`. [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732672/how-to-write-a-function-for-generic-numbers), I'm struggling to get this right with generic numbers.

```
module Seq =
    let inline private avgVarianceReducer toFloat (count, oldM, oldS) x =
        if count = 1 then
            2, x, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        else
            let meanFree = x - oldM
            let newM = oldM + meanFree / (toFloat count)
            count + 1, newM, oldS + meanFree * (x - newM)

    let inline private avgVarianceWith toFloat source =
        match source |> Seq.fold (avgVarianceReducer toFloat) (1, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero) with
        | 0, _, _ -> LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        | 1, mean, _ -> mean, LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        | n, mean, var -> mean, var / (n - 2 |> toFloat)

    let avgVariance source = source |> avgVarianceWith float
    let avgVariancef source = source |> avgVarianceWith float32
```

This works for both types, but I have the additional `avgVariancef` plus I have to choose the right one when calling.

To me the central problem is the conversion to the right kind of float in `avgVarianceReducer` which I solved by passing in the correct conversion funtion. I tried my way with `op_Explicit` but failed.

Anybody have an idea for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus)?
It contains a module for Generic Math and the generic `explicit` function you're looking for.

Here's how your code would look like:

```
#r @"FsControl.dll"
#r @"FSharpPlus.dll"

open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Operators.GenericMath

module Seq =
    let inline private avgVarianceReducer (count, oldM, oldS) (x:'R) =
        if count = 1 then
            2, x, 0G
        else
            let meanFree = x - oldM
            let newM = oldM + meanFree / explicit count
            count + 1, newM, oldS + meanFree * (x - newM)

    let inline avgVariance source : 'R * 'R =
        match source |> Seq.fold avgVarianceReducer (1, 0G, 0G) with
        | 0, _, _ -> 0G, 0G
        | 1, mean, _ -> mean, 0G
        | n, mean, var -> mean, var / (n - 2 |> explicit)

    // or if you prefer specific functions
    let avgVarianceF32 source : float32 * float32 = avgVariance source
    let avgVarianceF   source : float   * float   = avgVariance source

    // it will work with other types as well
    let avgVarianceD source : decimal * decimal   = avgVariance source
```

In fact you don't need the function `explicit`, you can use instead the function `fromIntegral` which is more specific for numbers.

You can also browse the source code of the library and extract only the code you need for your specific case.