# Why isn't it possible to use the same function twice with differently typed arguments?

Tags: f#, inline, type-inference

I played around a little with F# today, wrote this:

```
let sq x = x * x

let i = sq 3
let d = sq 3.0
```

It compiles if I remove either the third or the fourth line, but not if both are present.

I get the error `This expression should have type 'int', but has type 'float'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type inference works so that your function `sq` has type `int -> int`, because the first time compiler sees you use that function, you pass it an integer. So it assumes that `sq` is a function that takes an integer, and by definition of the function (`x * x`) it also returns an integer.

It is a bit complicated to define a fully generic arithmetic function in F#, but one way to do it is to make the function `inline`, like so:

```
let inline sq x = x * x
```

This way the body of your function will be inlined each time at the call site, so using an inlined `sq` function will be the same as substituting it's body every time it's used.

This approach has it's drawbacks, and I think it will be interesting for you to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225949/does-f-have-generic-arithmetic-support).

Comment: All answers correct (+1) as far as I can tell, I learned the most from yours though.

Answer (score 2):

Let-bound functions cannot be overloaded. In your specific case, you could use `inline`, which inlines the function body at compile time and can therefore choose an appropriate implementation of `*`, e.g.

```
let inline sq x = x * x
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct but they leave out an important part of the jigsaw: the fact that in F# there are no implicit conversions between, for example, ints and floats. This is the reason why your second call is in effect calling a different, non existent, overload with a float argument.

Answer (score 1):

The function `let sq x = x * x` on default has type `int -> int`.

If you put it in the context of a `let d = sq 3.0`, F# compiler will infer its type as `float -> float`.

In any way, this function can have only one type signature, either `int->int`, or `float->float`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in how the bindings are implemented.  There are 2 alternatives.

Firstly, add inline to the declaration.

Secondly, use member bindings in a class and override the different types.