# f# idiomatic type resolution solution for resolving to the wrong type

Tags: f#, inline, type-resolution

I'm just getting started with F# but I have some code that is analogous to the following:

```
let square x = x*x

let result = square 5.1

let result' = square 12
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error: `This expression was expected to have type float but here has type int`

Is there an idiomatic F# solution to this problem, or is my thinking being tainted by my C# experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write it like that:

```
let inline square x = x * x
```

Otherwise, after first time you used that `square` function, it type was inferred to be `float -> float`. Hence, and given that F# does not do automatic conversion from `int` to `float`, you receive an error.

So, if you don't want to use `inline`, the simplest solution is to write

```
 let result' = square (float 12)
```

It is simple and yet readable.

For more advanced solutions please take a look at this: [Does F# have generic arithmetic support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225949/does-f-have-generic-arithmetic-support)

But those solutions are (imho) incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

```
let inline square x = x * x

let result = square 5.1

let result' = square 12

printfn "%f" result
printfn "%d" result'
```

There's a whole article by Tomas Petricek on this subject:
http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/