# How can I hide methods in F#?

Tags: api, f#

I am currently implementing a Spec framework in F# and I want to hide the Equals, GetHashCode etc. methods on my `should` type, so that the API is not cluttered with these.

I know in C# it is done by making the class implement an interface like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public interface IFluentInterface
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    bool Equals(object other);

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    string ToString();

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    int GetHashCode();

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    Type GetType();
}
```

I tried doing the same in F#:

```
type IFluentInterface = interface

    [<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    abstract Equals : (obj) -> bool

    [<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    abstract ToString: unit -> string

    [<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    abstract GetHashCode: unit -> int

    [<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>]
    abstract GetType : unit -> Type 
end
```

Implemented it in my type:

```
        interface IFluentInterface with
        member x.Equals(other) = x.Equals(other)
        member x.ToString()    = x.ToString() 
        member x.GetHashCode() = x.GetHashCode()
        member x.GetType()     = x.GetType()
```

but without success.

I also tried to override the methods in my type and adding the attribute that way, but that didn't do the trick either.

So the question remains, how can I clean up my API ?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the help (see below) I was able to solve my problem.

In summary, `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` can be hidden via  `[<NoEquality>]` `[<NoComparison>]` but that will also change the semantics.

The hiding via EditorBrowsable attributes does not work.

The only way to have a clean API and still be able to overload methods is to make these method members static.

The resulting class can be found by browsing inside my project [FSharpSpec](http://github.com/thlorenz/FSharpSpec).

The type in question can be found [here.](http://github.com/thlorenz/FSharpSpec/blob/master/src/FSharpSpec/should.fs)

Thanks to everyone who helped me solve this problem.

Cheers ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you could design the library using an alternative style using functions enclosed in a module. This is the usual way for writing *functional* code in F# and then you won't need to hide any standard .NET methods. To complete the example given by 'kvb', here is an example of object-oriented solution:

```
type MyNum(n:int) =
  member x.Add(m) = MyNum(n+m)
  member x.Mul(m) = MyNum(n*m)

let n = new MyNum(1)
n.Add(2).Mul(10) // 'ToString' shows in the IntelliSense
```

The functional way of writing the code might look like this:

```
type Num = Num of int
module MyNum =
  let create n = Num n
  let add m (Num n) = Num (m + n)
  let mul m (Num n) = Num (m * n)

MyNum.create 1 |> MyNum.add 2 |> MyNum.mul 10
```

If you type `MyNum.`, the F# IntelliSense will show the functions defined in the module, so you won't see any noise in this case.

Comment: I'll look into that, I assume this approach will also allow me to overload the methods? -- On another note, I enjoyed your screen casts on F#.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, functions declared using `let` cannot be overloaded. Overloading is supported only for `member` declarations. See other SO questions on overloading in F# - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260939/f-overloading-functions

Comment: Well in that case I'd need to use a type, since I heavily depend on the ability to overload methods, you can imagine that a should.contain(actual, expected) needs to be implemented differently for strings than for sequences for example.
Is it possible to overload static members though? Obviously, if I would make my Assertion class and its members static, it wouldn't show any .ToString() ... methods.

Comment: Thanks, I changed them all to static and now got my cleaned up API (see edit of my question).

Answer (score 5):

Repeating my answer from

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13317.aspx

In F# you can disallow Equals & GetHashCode (and remove them from intellisense) by annotating the type with the NoEquality and NoComparison attributes, as shown below.  User-defined methods can also be hidden from the intellisense list via the Obsolete attribute or the CompilerMessage attribute with IsHidden=true.  There is no way to hide the System.Object methods GetType and ToString from the F# intellisense.

```
[<NoEquality; NoComparison>]
type Foo() =
    member x.Bar() = ()
    member x.Qux() = ()
    [<System.Obsolete>]
    member x.HideMe() = ()
    [<CompilerMessage("A warning message",99999,IsError=false,IsHidden=true)>]
    member x.WarnMe() = ()

let foo = new Foo()
foo.  // see intellisense here
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian I applied this change to clean it up somewhat. As I can see you found both places were I asked the question (I cover my bases).
Right now I am going to consider Tomas approach, since he is correct, that I don't need to use types, modules would do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is any way to do that in F# in general.  In the particular case of `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode`, you can make them unusable by putting a `[<NoEquality>]` attribute on your type, but this actually has a semantic effect in addition to hiding those methods.

**EDIT**

It might also be worth mentioning that fluent interfaces are rarely used in F#, since it's much more idiomatic to use combinators and pipelining instead.  For instance, imagine that we want to create a way to create arithmetic expressions.  Rather than

```
let x = Expressions.MakeExpr(1).Add(2).Mul(3).Add(4)
```

I think that most F# users would prefer to write

```
open Expressions
let x = 
  1
  |> makeExpr
  |> add 2
  |> mul 3
  |> add 4
```

With this style, there's no need to hide members because expressions get piped to combinators, rather than calling methods of an expression builder.

Comment: Thanks, I also had to put the [<NoComparison>] attribute, which I did. The affected semantics don't matter in this case.

Still need to hide ToString() and GetType(), but it looks much cleaner already.

Comment: @ "fluent interfaces are rarely used in F#"
I'm sorry, the name might be misleading, my sole purpose for this interface is to hide above mentioned methods.
I just happen to use this kind of interface a lot for creating fluent interfaces in C#.