# Why does a StaticallyResolvedTypeParameter method call compile when it fails at run-time?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, inline, static-typing

I've just written a simple method that C# can see but calling it (even with valid arguments) throws up at run-time.

example that fails at runtime:

F#:

```
namespace Library1
type Class1() = 
  member __.Foo = "F#"
module MyModule = 
  // fails at run-time
  let inline fOnly (x:^a) : string = (^a:(member Foo: _) x)
  // works from C# and F# so I know it's not a problem with my stp
  let testFOnly () = fOnly (Class1())
```

C# consumer:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
    class Program
    {
      var class1 = new Library1.Class1();
      // NotSupportedException
      var result = Library1.MyModule.fOnly(class1);
      Console.ReadLine();    
    }
  }
```

Why does this compile, then fail at run-time? Am I doing something wrong or should I just assume any attempt to call an [stp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) method from C# will always fail? Should I then [attempt to hide them from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388565/how-can-i-hide-methods-in-f)?

Answer (score 2):

The use of `inline` in F# doesn't actually produce a function in the output assembly.

The function is encoded in some metadata that only the F# compiler can read and then insert inline.

As a result, you cannot call `inline` functions from C#

Comment: the c# to call this compiles. Also the following compiles and works `let inline add x y = x + y`  called from C# as `var inlinedAdd = Library1.MyModule.add<int,int,int>(1,2);` so apparently you can call `inline` functions from C# ?

Comment: @Maslow - this surprises me - maybe the compiler creates a backup non-inline version where it can?

Comment: what suprises me is people upvoted an answer that it took a simple add function to disprove.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the example is wrong

`Class1` has the member `Foo` not `X` and it fails to compile

[image]

-------------- After Question Edit ------------

You can use ILSpy to see the decompiled code and the source of the error

Decompiled C# -

```csharp
namespace Library1
{
    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
    public static class MyModule
    {
        public static string fOnly<a>(a x)
        {
            "Dynamic invocation of get_Foo is not supported";
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public static string testFOnly()
        {
            Class1 @class = new Class1();
            return "F#";
        }
    }
}
```

But you can see from the code that this will work

```
static void Main ( string [ ] args )
{
  Console.WriteLine( Library1.MyModule.testFOnly()) ;
  Console.ReadLine();  
}
```

There's also no reason to make this a function call 
`let testFOnly () = fOnly (Class1())` 
instead of a regular binding since it's targeting an immutable property of the class.

i.e. `let testFOnly =  Class1() |> fOnly`

Comment: my bad, adjusted only half the F# to make it slightly more readable for an SO question, updated question

Comment: I'm really surprised it doesn't embed a call to the member as inlined, and instead grabs the compile-time value, maybe it would do something more interesting/intuitive if it was pointed at a function instead of a prop/field with a constant value