# Pipeline operator refuses to work

Tags: generics, f#, pipeline

I can't understand why this

```
let data = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(
         File.ReadAllText <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json"))
```

is ok, while this

```
let data = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> 
    <| File.ReadAllText
    <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json")
```

Gives me two errors, first is:

[image: First error]

and second is:

[image: Second error]

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE** @Patryk Ćwiek suggested a good edit, which seems to fix errors with types:

```
let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> 
       << File.ReadAllText 
       <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json")
```

But it produces another puzzling message: Unexpected type arguments. 
Here's a screenshot:

[image: Unexpected type arguments.]

I can easily get rid of it removing `<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>` but in this case my data is of `object` type, not a `Dictionary`. Can I somehow save type information an use pipelining as well?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @Patryk Ćwiek solution is as follows:

```
let d<'a>(s:string) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(s)
let data = 
    Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json") 
    |> File.ReadAllText 
    |> d<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> with
```

I don't know why, but without that alias `d` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the evaluation goes from left to right, so your second expression is an equivalent of:

```
let data = 
    (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> <| File.ReadAllText)
    <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json")
```

Notice how the operations flow. That means that you're passing a function to `DeserializeObject` first, probably not what you meant to do.

When you do this:

```
let data = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> 
    <| (File.ReadAllText <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json"))
```

it will work. It's an equivalent of your first option.

Other solution is to invert piping to make the data flow more naturally:

```
let data = Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json") 
           |> File.ReadAllText 
           |> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

#### Edit

I've overlooked one option, that's not-so-commonly used. You can use function composition operator `<<` to make it work, too:

```
let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> 
           << File.ReadAllText 
           <| Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json")
```

It essentially combines `DeserializeObject : string -> 'a` and `ReadAllText : string -> string` into (unnamed in the example above) function `f : string -> 'a`, where `f(s) = DeserializeObject(ReadAllText(s))`. Then it feeds the result of `Path.Combine` via pipe into `f`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unforunately both ways you suggest lead to a same stange error: Unexpected type arguments. I attach screenshot in the update

Comment: @Rustam What is the full signature of `DeserializeObject`? Quite possibly, if there are multiple overloads, F# may have problems picking the right one. To 'test' piping and composition, I actually used a stub method `let deserialize<'a>(s : string) = Unchecked.defaultof<'a>`, which is a `string -> 'a` function.

Comment: All methods are listed here: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm

Comment: There are both generic and simple methods there, with several overloads

Comment: @Rustam I *think* it's the overload resolution issue, because both methods take `String`, but one is not generic and returns `Object`, and second one is generic in `T`. 'Aliasing' the method by `let deserialize<'a>(s : string) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(s)` and using the function later on should work...

Comment: Yes! Aliasing helped! Now it is like that:         `let data = 
            Path.Combine(myPath, "ejv.json")
            |> File.ReadAllText
            |> d<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>` with `let d<'a>(s:string) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>(s)`

Comment: @Rustam Glad it worked. :) I'm not quite sure what overload resolution rules are in F#, but as someone [smarter than me once said - admittedly, in different context - *overloading is typically the bugaboo of type-inferenced languages*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/501356/1180426)