# Why does the argument type of arithmetic operators default to int?

Tags: f#

I am new to F#, and I was surprised to find that the type of `f x y = x + y` is actually `int -> int -> int`. [Appearently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501069/functions-with-generic-parameter-types/501356#501356), this is due to some performance trade-off.

But *why* is this actually necessary? Why not just infer the type to be `'a -> 'a -> 'a` or something similar? It seems to work for comparison: the type of `g x y = x < y` is `x:'a -> y:'a -> bool when 'a : comparison`. Why not for arithmetic operators as well?

Couldn't the compiler statically infer the specific primitive types from the call sites and specialize the generic function from there, falling back to some dynamic dispatch if this fails?

This might very well be obvious, but I could not find any good resources on this. What is the reasoning behind this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, for those operators `int` is the default type inferred unless you specify a different one or is inferred by the use. If you want to define them for all types you have to make the function inline:

```
let inline f x y = x + y
```

But notice that the signature is:

```
x: ^a -> y: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

This is because in .NET you can't use [member constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) but F# resolves them at compile time. That's why you see those 'hat types' and the constraint that those type should have a static member (+) defined.

Also notice the type variables are not `a -> a -> a` as you suggest, that's because in the .NET framework not all addition operations respect that signature. Things are different in other environments like Haskell, there the addition is strictly `a -> a -> a` but in .NET you can add for instance a TimeSpan to a DateTime:

```
System.DateTime(2000,1,1) + new System.TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 30, 0)
```

and the result it's a DateTime, here the signature is: `a -> b -> a`

Comparison is a different story since that constraint actually exists at .NET level so it can be compiled and encoded in the IL whereas member constraints need to be resolved at compile time, that why the function has to be marked as inline.

I think you misinterpreted the explanation in the linked question: this is not due a performance trade-off, the real reason is a .NET type system limitation. The fact that an inline function executes faster in most cases (since it's inlined by the compiler) is a secondary effect.

Comment: Thank you for this quick and excellent answer. "in .NET you can't use member constraints" <- this is what I had not realized. I don't know why, but I somehow just assumed it to be possible. Probably I should RTFM before asking any more questions ;)

Comment: I'm confused by one statement on the msdn site. In the table it says: "An inline function cannot be parameterized with a standard generic type parameter." However, `let inline g a b = a, b` will give me `g : a:'a -> b:'b -> 'a * 'b`. For me this contradicts the statement. What am I missing?

Comment: I think that last row is a bit confusing. I had wrote it the other way: Feature = "Use with non inline functions" Generic="Yes" StaticallyResolved="No, it must be inline". But nothing prevents the Generic to be inline.