# F# what is the type of (+)

Tags: types, f#

I am new to F#. I tried finding the type of few values like (+), pown etc.
Though I vaguely understand that (int -> int -> int) means “a function taking an integer, which returns a function which takes an integer and returns an integer.”

But, I don't understand the meaning of `<fun:it@1>` in

```
(+);;  
val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@1>
```

Any help in understanding the concept would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/defining-functions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using F# Interactive (`fsi`) to evaluate expressions. In that case this is how you should read the output of the program:

- `val it` => denotes the binding to the last evaluated expression
- `: (int -> int -> int)` => following the colon is the type of the last evaluated expression
- `= <fun:it@1>` => following the equal sign is the value of the last evaluated  expression

So you can see that you already answered your question about the type of `( + )`. The part you are asking about is just the value of the function and `fsi` cannot display anything meaningful here. If you try to define your own function, you will get a similar result: `let f x = x + 1;; f;;` yields `val it : (int -> int) = <fun:it@4>`.

Now, to fully answer the question about the [type of `( + )`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L1769), this is a bit tricky since it is an overloaded operator and require more advanced knowledge to understand. Basically, if there exists a class with a static member named `( + )` with inputs of type `^T1` and `^T2` then you can use the `( + )` operator on values of type `^T1` and `^T2`.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the tricky type of `(+)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186464/why-does-the-argument-type-of-arithmetic-operators-default-to-int

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Coming from imperative background, I tend to relate / compare concepts with C / C++ equivalents. These languages allowed passing function pointers as parameters for callbacks. Not too sure, but, can function values in F# be thought of to be somewhat similar to function pointers of C / C++...

Comment: I guess it can't hurt to make this analogy but actually function values are passed around as instances of the [`FSharpFunc` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.fsharpfunc%5B't,'u%5D-class-%5Bfsharp%5D)